# File operation in android

Tags: android

I am new to android platform. I need to create a text file in android. Please let me know how to perform this task in android. I have written a code that is working fine in java but not in android. Please help me on this....the sample code that ihave written is :-

```
try
{
DataOutputStream   dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.txt", true));
dos.writeBytes(dataLine);
dos.close();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {}
```

the above code snippet is working fine in java but not in android :(

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 1):

The Android Dev Guide [explains it nicely](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal):

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

If you want the files you create to be visible to the outside world, use [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).  But as I said in the comment, make sure you're "being a good citizen".  These files stick around even after the user uninstalls your app.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply...but the file is still not created using above snippet...also let me know the path where the file is getting created

Comment: It gets created in your private dedicated "world".  If you want it to be visible to the rest of the world then use external storage.  But think long and hard about that.  Are your files really important enough to keep around when the user uninstalls your app?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
final File sdcard=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            File path=new File(sdcard,"textfile.txt");
            try {

                BufferedWriter wr=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
                wr.write("Your Text Here");
                wr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Also you need to add following permission to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Static methods used for common file operations.
 * 
 * @author Carl Hartung (carlhartung@gmail.com)
 */
public class FileUtils {
    private final static String t = "FileUtils";

    // Used to validate and display valid form names.
    public static final String VALID_FILENAME = "[ _\\-A-Za-z0-9]*.x[ht]*ml";

    // Storage paths
    public static final String FORMS_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/odk/forms/";
    public static final String INSTANCES_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/odk/instances/";
    public static final String CACHE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/odk/.cache/";
    public static final String TMPFILE_PATH = CACHE_PATH + "tmp.jpg";


    public static ArrayList<String> getValidFormsAsArrayList(String path) {
        ArrayList<String> formPaths = new ArrayList<String>();
        File dir = new File(path);

        if (!storageReady()) {
            return null;
        }
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            if (!createFolder(path)) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        File[] dirs = dir.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++) {
          // skip all the directories
          if (dirs[i].isDirectory())
            continue;

            String formName = dirs[i].getName();

          formPaths.add(dirs[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return formPaths;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getFoldersAsArrayList(String path) {
        ArrayList<String> mFolderList = new ArrayList<String>();
        File root = new File(path);

        if (!storageReady()) {
            return null;
        }
        if (!root.exists()) {
            if (!createFolder(path)) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        if (root.isDirectory()) {
            File[] children = root.listFiles();
            for (File child : children) {
                boolean directory = child.isDirectory();
                if (directory) {
                    mFolderList.add(child.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
        return mFolderList;
    }


    public static boolean deleteFolder(String path) {
        // not recursive
        if (path != null && storageReady()) {
            File dir = new File(path);
            if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
                File[] files = dir.listFiles();
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (!file.delete()) {
                        Log.i(t, "Failed to delete " + file);
                    }
                }
            }
            return dir.delete();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public static boolean createFolder(String path) {
        if (storageReady()) {
            boolean made = true;
            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                made = dir.mkdirs();
            }
            return made;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public static boolean deleteFile(String path) {
        if (storageReady()) {
            File f = new File(path);
            return f.delete();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public static byte[] getFileAsBytes(File file) {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(file);

            // Get the size of the file
            long length = file.length();
            if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                Log.e(t, "File " + file.getName() + "is too large");
                return null;
            }

            // Create the byte array to hold the data
            bytes = new byte[(int) length];

            // Read in the bytes
            int offset = 0;
            int read = 0;
            try {
                while (offset < bytes.length && read >= 0) {
                    read = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset);
                    offset += read;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(t, "Cannot read " + file.getName());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

            // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
            if (offset < bytes.length) {
                try {
                    throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file.getName());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }

            return bytes;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(t, "Cannot find " + file.getName());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        } finally {
            // Close the input stream
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(t, "Cannot close input stream for " + file.getName());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }


    public static boolean storageReady() {
        String cardstatus = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (cardstatus.equals(Environment.MEDIA_REMOVED)
                || cardstatus.equals(Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE)
                || cardstatus.equals(Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED)
                || cardstatus.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


    public static String getMd5Hash(File file) {
        try {
            // CTS (6/15/2010) : stream file through digest instead of handing it the byte[]
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            int chunkSize = 256;

            byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkSize];

            // Get the size of the file
            long lLength = file.length();

            if (lLength > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                Log.e(t, "File " + file.getName() + "is too large");
                return null;
            }

            int length = (int) lLength;

            InputStream is = null;
            is = new FileInputStream(file);

            int l = 0;
            for (l = 0; l + chunkSize < length; l += chunkSize) {
                is.read(chunk, 0, chunkSize);
                md.update(chunk, 0, chunkSize);
            }

            int remaining = length - l;
            if (remaining > 0) {
                is.read(chunk, 0, remaining);
                md.update(chunk, 0, remaining);
            }
            byte[] messageDigest = md.digest();

            BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);
            String md5 = number.toString(16);
            while (md5.length() < 32)
                md5 = "0" + md5;
            is.close();
            return md5;

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("MD5", e.getMessage());
            return null;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("No Cache File", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Problem reading from file", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } 


    }

}
```